# HTML rendering model as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a fork from another question.  I am passing a list into a partial view which is part of a main view.  However, when I view the page, I see:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...Models.OutcomeArea] List
```

Now, the list is being rendered correctly, but I am not sure why the above line is showing in the html.

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    @Html.Action("_Checklist")
}
```

_Checklist.cshtml:

```
@Model List<....Models.OutcomeArea>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="text-center">Outcomes</h4>
        <p>
        @foreach (var list in Model)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" id="@list.ID" name="@list.ID" /> @list.Category <br />
        }
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

SearchController:

```
public PartialViewResult _Checklist()
    {
        var outcomeAreas = db.OutcomeArea.Where(oa => oa.Category != "").GroupBy(oa => oa.Category).Select(oa => oa.FirstOrDefault());
        return PartialView("_Checklist", outcomeAreas.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Where in the HTML does it show it?  What is the rendered output?

Comment: The first part of the string looks like the standard `ToString()` from the `List<....Models.OutcomeArea>` object.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have it working.  I needed to use lowercase @model for the _Checklist.cshtml.

```
@model List<....Models.OutcomeArea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Took a while to spot the bug. Tricky one, this. Your model declaration is the problem:

```
@Model List<....Models.OutcomeArea>
```

That should be `@model`, lowercase. You're literally telling to print out `Model` at the moment.